# Interceptor not being called on Payara 5.184

Tags: java, cdi, interceptor, java-ee-7, payara

I am running a simple Maven Java EE web project on Payara

I am trying demonstrate the working of Interceptor but it isn't getting called. I have even defined it in a beans.xml file

- Payara Version: 5.184
- Edition: Full
- JDK Version: 1.8, Java EE 7
- Operating System: Mac
- Database: Oracle

**Bean class**

```
package com.maven.web;

import com.interceptors.LogNameInterceptor;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptors;

@ManagedBean
@Stateless
public class UserBean implements User {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(UserBean.class.getName());

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    @Interceptors(LogNameInterceptor.class)
    public String show(String fn, String ln) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Inside method");
        return "result";
    }

}
```

**User.java**

```
package com.maven.web;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface User {

    public String show(String a, String b);
}
```

**Interceptor class**

```
package com.interceptors;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

@Interceptor
public class LogNameInterceptor {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LogNameInterceptor.class.getName());

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object aroundInvoke(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Inside Interceptor");
        System.out.println(ctx.getMethod());
        return ctx.proceed();
    }
}
```

**beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

    <interceptors>
        <class>com.interceptors.LogNameInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

Only 'Inside method' is printed in the log, meaning it doesn't reach the aroundInvoke method
Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you obtaining the instance of the `UserBean` on which you invoke `show()`? I suspect it is through JSF - in this case, can you try without the `@ManagedBean` annotation?

Comment: Here's a sample project from the Jakarta EE tutorial that does a very similar thing to what you do: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jakartaee-tutorial-examples/tree/master/ejb/interceptor. I tried it on Payara 5.183 and it works. Does it work for you on 5.184?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Yes the application uses JSF. Without the managed bean annotation, the application will fail!

Comment: @OndroMih The project doesnt build well.

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.7.7:redeploy

Comment: I may be wrong, but I always had the impression that CDI interceptors need an interceptor binding (which you don't have). See https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/interceptors.html for details.

Comment: @mtj, these are not CDI interceptors but EJB interceptors.

Comment: @Nath, the cargo maven plugin fails to deploy the sample application. Try to just build the sample project with `mvn package -DskipTests=true` and then deploy the WAR separately. And, by the way, your code uses EJB interceptors, and not CDI interceptors. Therefore beans.xml file has no effect. The rest of the code looks OK so I don't know what's wrong. The example project works for me though so try to look what's different.

Comment: @OndroMih Thanks, the sample project works well on my PC too. But, I still couldn't figure out what's wrong with my implementation. 

Also I noticed the author hasn't specified the @ Interceptor annotation. Is that allowed?

Comment: Yes, the specification allows it. The Interceptor annotation is optional for EJB interceptors as the class is already referenced from the annotation on the intercepted method. This is different to CDI interceptors where the intercepted method isn't directly coupled with its interceptor and an annotation on the interceptor class is required to enable it.